# Angular 4: View is not updating after model change?

Tags: angular, model, angularjs-scope, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have two `component` in my app ie: `HeaderComponent` & `TestComponent`. In `HeaderComponent`, There is a method name **setUserData()**.
I am calling this **setUserDate()** from **TestComponent's method `ansSubmit()`** which is in file `test.component.ts`.

Now `setUserDate()` is calling and value is coming in `setUserDate()` method.

**The problem is :** when `setUserDate()` calling , I am setting score value into **this.userData.score**, And **this.userData.score** value is binding in view ( HTML ) but the coming value from 
**TestComponent's method ansSubmit() is not going to update on the view** but the value is present in the `ts` file ( I am printing in console).

**Here is the code:**

**test.component.ts:**

```
import { HeaderComponent } from '../../components/header/header.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'test-page',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css'],
  providers: [HeaderComponent]
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  private userData: any = {};

  constructor(private _router: Router, private headerComponent: HeaderComponent) { }

  ansSubmit() {
    const logged_in_user = new LocalStorage(environment.localStorageKeys.ADMIN);
    this.userData = logged_in_user.value;
    this.userData['score'] = parseInt(this.userData.score) + 54321 

    this.headerComponent.getUserData(this.userData['score']); // Calling HeaderComponent's method  value is 54321.
  }
}
```

**test.component.html:**

```
 <div class="col-2">
     <button (click)="ansSubmit()" >
          <div>Submit Answer</div>
      </button>
</div>
```

**header.component.ts:**

```
import {
  Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef, NgZone, ApplicationRef, ChangeDetectionStrategy
} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],

})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    public userData : any = {
      score:2000,
   };

  getUserData(score) { // score= 54321  ( value is coming )  
       this.userData.score = score ;
       console.log(this.userData.score);  // in this.userData.score = 54321  ( Value is assigning )
     } 
  }
}
```

**header.component.html:**

```
<span class="topbar-details">
            Scrore : {{userData.score }}  // actual problem is here, Its not updating value. Its only showing 2000.
</span>
```

**Please suggest me how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: different component?

Comment: yes, I am calling this method from a different component. By using :   this.headerComponent.getUserData(this.userData['score']);

Comment: can u add some code in stackblitz.com and share it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the reason you are struggling is because it seems like you have sibling components trying to manipulate data in which neither one is truly the owner of the data.  Angular tries to enforce [Unidirectional Data Flow](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-what-is-unidirectional-data-flow-development-mode/) which simply means data flows from the parent to the child instead of the child to the parent.  The simplest way to solve your issue would be to have parent component that "owns" the userData and the child components bind to the data to display it and emit events to manipulate it.

Using your scenario as an example:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public userData: any = {
    score: 2000
};

 updateScore(score: number): void {
   this.userData.score += score;
 }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header [score]="userData.score"></app-header>
<app-test (onScoreChange)="updateScore($event)"></app-test>
```

**header.component.ts**

import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('score') score: number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**header.component.html**

```
<span class="topbar-details">
  Scrore : {{score}}
</span>
```

**test.component.ts**

import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output('onScoreChange') onScoreChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ansSubmit() {
    this.onScoreChange.emit(54321);
  }
}
```

**test.component.html**

```
<div class="col-2">
  <button (click)="ansSubmit()" >
    <div>Submit Answer</div>
  </button>
</div>
```

**Note:** As far as loading the user information from local storage, I would use a service to handle that.  Where and how the user data gets loaded is not really a concern of the components that are displaying and manipulating the data.  Moving that logic to a service with the proper interface (likely returning observables if the data could ever possibly come from a remote location) will allow you to seamlessly swap out a local storage based service for an HTTP based service to force all scores to be transmitted to/from a server without changing a line of code in your component.  It would also allow you to swap in a mock service for testing so local storage does not need to be seeded in order for the test to pass (i.e. - your tests have to know less about the implementation of your component to pass, so they will not be as fragile upon implementation changes)

Answer (score 2):

You are adding HeaderComponent as a provider, so it's probably creating a new instance of the component. If you have an existing HeaderComponent, you will need to get ahold of that instance, so using a service would be helpful to keep a reference to the component instance.

It would be best to move the score to the service altogether and use a Subject to update its value. Check out their documentation: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service. Really any strategies listed in that documentation should be useful for your situation.

Comment: I agree with moving the functionality to a service. Another solution would be to move the functionality to a parent component and utilize event @Output to get the render engine detection the changes properly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the problem is there are serveral `HeaderComponent` more than one. Maybe, it is caused by your injection which is

`constructor(private _router: Router, private headerComponent: HeaderComponent) { }`.

Try this code the below to figure out what cause the issue.

**header.component.ts**

```
import {
  Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef, NgZone, ApplicationRef, ChangeDetectionStrategy
} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],

})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    static count:number = 0;
    public id:number = 0;
    public userData : any = {
      score:2000,
    };

    constructor(){
      HeaderComponent.count++;
      this.id = HeaderComponent.count
    }

    getUserData(score) { // score= 54321  ( value is coming )  
       this.userData.score = score ;
       console.log(`${this._id} : ${this.userData.score}`);  // in this.userData.score = 54321  ( Value is assigning )
    } 
  }
}
```

**header.component.html**

```
<span>id : {{id}}</span>
<span class="topbar-details">
   Scrore : {{userData.score }}  // actual problem is here, Its not updating value. Its only showing 2000.
</span>
```

If **id** in the view and **id** in the console are different, it means you are not updating `HeaderComponent` instance in the view but another `HeaderComponent` instance which print log in console.

Pleas try this and tell me the results. Thank you.

Comment: I tried the same, But it's not updating the old value on the view.

Comment: Oh, did you also try to set new value to old value in **callback function** in `this._ngZone.run`?

Comment: yes, I tried this._ngZone.run, But its also not updating the model on the view.

Comment: Then, I need more information to solve it. Could you share more details?

Comment: Hi @Hyuck Kang I have updated my question please have a look and response accordingly.

Comment: @Shubham Verma I updated my anwser. Please read and try it. I will wait for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to get information from one component and display in another you should use events.

Component Data:

```
@Output() userDataEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
----
getUserData(score?){
      this.score=score?score:this.userData.score;     
      console.log("getUserData called :"+this.score);  
      this.userDataEvent.emit(this.score);
 }
```

Display Component:

```
<your-component (userDataEvent)='setUserData($event)'></your-component>
```

And then, `setUserData` is a function which introduce you to the data from your other component

Comment: This is not a parent & child component.

Comment: So please provide more information ... its not clear what you are trying to do and how.

Comment: Hi @dAxx I have updated my question have a look and response accordingly.

Comment: Hi @ dAxx_ It's not emitting the setUserData() when this.userDataEvent.emit(this.score); called.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing to OnChanges to the HeaderComponent

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
   // do your action
 }
}
```

I suggest you using the angular service or @Output and emit events in the root and listen them in the header.
Please have a look at basic types of reactivity provided by angular. 
The OnChanges listener is for listening to changes done outside angular (like a library).
You should use this as a last resort only!

Comment: I tried with ngOnChanges() but it's not working.
And I don't need parent-child component, So I don't want to implement parent-child component.
Both are the different component.

Comment: If they are different components, you can use a angular service, inject it in your class and use it. This simplifies so many things. Have a common data in the service and use it to render in the component. Will work for even unrelated components.